# Oracle does not allow to create "USER" table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, reserved-words

Oracle is not allowing to create `USER` table.

Can anyone guide me to create `USER` table in Oracle.?

TIA.

Comment: `USER` is reserver word in Oracle, you must use quotes around this name: `CREATE TABLE "USER" (col1 int..... (`. Btw - you will have to use quotes in all of your sql commands (all SELECT inserts and uptates), this will be tedious, it would be easier if you picked other name thah `USER`

Answer (score 7):

Can you use a different name like my_user or something else. If you are insistent about using the table name user then you will have to provide the table name in quotes.

```
CREATE TABLE "USER"
(
col1 NUMBER(10)
)
```

You, will have to use quotes and maintain the upper case when doing any operations on this table.

The following will give you an error.

```
select * from USER;

ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

However, the following will work.

```
select * from "USER";
```

That said I don't recommend this option and it would be good if you can change your table name.

Answer (score 3):

`USER` is a reserved keyword in [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle). Thus it can't be used directly.

Here is the list of [*restricted keywords*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) a.k.a *reserved words*.

e.g. you can't either create a table called `TABLE`...